# JSF 2.0 Navigation Not Working

Tags: jsf, navigation

I am using Netbeans 7.0, Glassfish 3.1, JSF 2.0
I am trying to navigate from one view to another in a step-wise user registration process (with three steps). Each  step corresponds to a view and these views are in different folders but all have the same name, i.e register.xhtml. i have tried implicit navigation whereby i specify the absolute path of the views in a managed bean event listener and also using the faces-config.xml navigation cases.

The problem is that i can navigate from the first step/view to the next step/view without a problem. Navigating to the third view however results in a com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException

the file structure is like

```
/extensions/assm/registration/individual/register.xhtml
/extensions/assm/registration/address/register.xhtml
/extensions/assm/registration/systemuser/register.xhtml
```

extract of faces-config.xml for navigating from address to systemuser

```
<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id></from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
<from-outcome>gotosystemuser</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/extensions/aasm/registration/systemuser/register.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

anyone out there know where i am getting it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException`

means that JSF is not able to locate the view. The `view id` you have specified in the `navigation-rule` is not good (somehow).

A view is identified by the path with everything after the `context root`, including the `/` at the beginning.

But you also have to include the `URL pattern` that's mapped with the `Faces Servlet` in `web.xml`. 
e.g. if in your web.xml if you have

```
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/jsf/*</url-pattern>
```

then you have to also include that as the `View ID`. So, with the view id will be

> /jsf/folder1/folder2/page.xhtml

But with JSF 2.0 you don't need to do all that navigation-rule in the `faces-config` file. 
In JSF 2.0 to navigate to another page all you need to do is return the view id from the action method.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

    public String axnMethod() {
        return "view-id"; //this will result in navigation to view represented by view-id
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bhesh Gurung, I have really tried both approaches, the action listener as well as the navigation-rule approach and it's not working. There really has to be another explanation as the very same approach is working for the first two views. if i change the navigation rule to point to any one of the previous contexts i.e folder address or folder individual, it works just fine but any other context it will not work.

Comment: i have just deleted the systemuser folder and created another one called sysuser. Now it works! could someone out there explain to me what is going on. I am new to JSF. Thanks

Comment: @ltmutiwekuziwa: Can you post your faces servlet declaration and mapping and managed bean code and is extensions folder in the same level as WEB-INF? (Also if you are really using JSF 2.0 then you are just wasting your time doing all this.)

Comment: My apologies for late response. here goes;  `code`                     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: `code` public String gotoSystemUser(){ return "/extensions/aasm/registration/systemuser/register.xhtml";}

Comment: @ltmutiwekuziwa: Have you tried `public String gotoSystemUser(){ return "/faces/extensions/aasm/registration/systemuser/register.xhtml";}`?

Comment: @ltmutiwekuziwa: Can you also try changine `<from-view-id></from-view-id>` to `<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>`? Or you can just comment out that line.

Comment: @ltmutiwekuziwa: Can you update your post with view-code, managed-bean code, and the Stacktrace?